# Page Inspector doesn't work in Visual Studio Preview 2015

Tags: visual-studio, page-inspector

For some odd reason, I can't get Visual Studio Page Inspector to work. There's no option for view under page inspector. Also, the browser link on Chrome doesn't work either.

I have VS 2013 installed on the same machine.  I tried enabling it in the web.config and I also installed the latest VS Update 4 for VS 2013, hoping it will install the necessary tools.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Perhaps Page Inspector is not yet available in VS 2015? I'm using VS 2015 RC (v 14.0.22823.1 D14 REL) and there's no ["View in Page Inspector"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/ASP-NET-Site-Videos/Visual-Studio-2013-Web-Editor-Features-Page-Inspector) in the context menu when I right click on an index.html. This visual studio blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/11/12/visual-studio-2015-preview-visual-studio-community-2013-visual-studio-2013-update-4-and-more.aspx) from 12 Nov 2014 post seems to suggest that inspectors should be supportd

Comment: I gave up on 2015 and went back to 2013. Microsoft's products are severely broken and you'd think after over 30 years in business, billions of dollars in revenue and thousands of employees that they would get simple things right. I sometimes just want to go into another field where things just work.

Comment: Doubt it's broken - just not part of the RC. Maybe they'll add it to the RTM. Then again perhaps source maps and browser-sync is the way to go. I have opened a ticket here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/1412439/page-inspector-missing.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Browser Link Dashboard" from the Refresh button close to Run button, then in the Connection list, click on "View in Browser". That's all.